# Isomorphism of Group Onto A Proper Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Suppose an abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of itself $H$. One easy example of this are the integers which are isomorphic to the even integers. One can easily generalise this: the integers are isomorphic to integer multiples of any non-zero integer. Hence, in the case of the integers, an isomorphism onto a subgroup can be defined as $ f(x) = nx$, $n \neq 0$ and one can show with a little bit of work that these are the $ only$ possible isomorphisms of the integers onto a subgroup of themselves. Now, my question is, is this true for abelian groups in general? Are the only possible isomorphisms of an abelian group onto a subgroup given by $f(x)=nx$ for non-zero integers $n$?

Comment: Take $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and map $(x,y) \mapsto (2x,y)$. Same spirit, but it doesn't fit your conditions. Of course, from this, you can construct a bunch of them that don't fit your condition.

Comment: hmm... how could I modify the conditions then.. the example does have the "same spirit" as you said so it seems a slight extension of the possible isomorphisms might work then?

Comment: Recall that every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$ module. All you have to do is understand all possible $\mathbb{Z}$ module structures!

Comment: Consider the map from infinitely many copies of the integers to itself, $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ goes to $(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$.

Comment: ok, I see there truly are countless possiblities